# Rails many-to-many :through association nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my rails project I have three models:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolments
  has_many :users, through: :enrolments , :foreign_key => :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrolments

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolments
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolments , :foreign_key => :subject_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrolments

class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

subjects_controller.rb

```
 class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @subject = Subject.new
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @subject.enrolments.build(:user_id => @user.id)
  end


  def create
    @subject= Subject.create(subject_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subject.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Subject was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subject }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

 def subject_params
     params.require(:subject).permit(:name,
     enrolments_attributes: [ :user_id, :subject_id, :_destroy, user_attributes: [ :id, :email,  :_destroy]]
    )
 end
end
```

View (for testing, will use cocoon to insert multiple users):

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px;">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <%= form_for @subject, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <fieldset id="recipe-meta">
    <ol>
      <li class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :name, "Subject name", class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
      <%= f.fields_for :enrolments do |enrolment| %>
        <%= enrolment.hidden_field :subject_id %>
    <%= enrolment.fields_for :user , User.new do |enrolment_user| %>
     <%= enrolment_user.label :email %>
      <%= enrolment_user.text_field :email %>
    <% end %>
     <% end %>
  </fieldset>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Intention: Create subject at the same time manually register an user account for students a multiple field (email) then insert into multiple user_id into enrolment table.

Example enrolment table:

```
id   user_id    subject_id
--------------------------------------
1     2           1   
2     3           1  
3     4           1
```

**Update(Code now works):**

> add `@subject.enrolment.build` to SubjectController `def new` method

Comment: User is inside enrollment, not subject ?

Answer (score 0):

You added users to your nested form but you forgot to add them to your controller parameters whitelisting. Make sure users are defined correctly in your subject_params method in SubjectsController.

From my comments below:

@JackGoh: your subject_params are wrong, but it is not related to your email field not showing. Probably, this will fix email not showing @subject.enrolments.build(user: @user).

Comment: I added subject_params method in SubjectsController & EnrolmentController, users_attributes: [ :id, :email,  :_destroy]. Still show the same error. here's my log :

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nrosOiJHQeOOFQ+wL2RS/FlONOUTl3YddN+JtE88vpQcZ+AqcL3O1FmDLUwdj5Znb88oLhP8IpZRJzbc3fYpdQ==", “subject"=>{"name"=>"123", "enrolments_attributes"=>{"1438596478232"=>{"users"=>{"id"=>"", "email"=>"123@123.com"}, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Subject"}

Comment: @JackGoh, your Enrolment model has "accepts_nested_attributes_for :user" not "users". So, your fields_for should have :user and not ":users. Please add your form to the question, if it does not work.

Comment: @JackGoh, and it is user_attributes: [ :id, :email, :_destroy] not users_attributes.

Comment: @JackGoh: your subject_params are wrong, but it is not related to your email field not showing. Probably, this will fix email not showing @subject.enrolments.build(user: @user)

Answer (score 0):

The nesting in the controller differs from the nesting specified in the views and models. Perhaps try this:

```
params.require(:subject).permit(
  :name,
  enrolments_attributes: [
    :user_id, :subject_id, :_destroy, 
    user_attributes: [:id, :email,  :_destroy]
  ]
)
```

Also, I would recommend rewriting the model, view and controller for "enrolments" as "enrollments".